# Add env variable in package.json brefore cypress runs in headless mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, cypress, cross-env

I want to find out if cypress runs or doesn't run in the NextJS application. My idea is prevent a some http requests in the NextJS application if the Cypress tests are running.

I am able to catch if cypress is running when I run "npx cypress open" for a  browser like this:

```js
if(window.Cypress){
 // prevent http request or do something
}
```

But I am not able to check if the cypress is running or not in headless mode with `"npx cypress run"` command.

I tried to add extra env variable in the `package.json` file like in below:

```js
...
"cy:run": "cross-env CY_MODE=true cypress run",
...
```

But it doesn't set the CY_MODE env variable when I try to log `process.env.CY_MODE`.

How can I set a custom environment variable before cypress tests start with headless mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [Exposing Environment Variables to the Browser](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

> By default environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they won't be exposed to the browser.
>
> In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the variable with **NEXT_PUBLIC_**.

```js
"cy:run": "cross-env NEXT_PUBLIC_CY_MODE=true cypress run",
```

---

Alternatively, you can control the NextJs server from Cypress plugins - see [Mock Network When Using Next.js getServerSideProps Call](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/mock-network-from-server/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set env.variables inside package.json:

- create parent command where you define env.variable and contain your command for running tests `'parentCommand': 'cross-env CY_MODE=true npx cypress run'`
- launch the command and env variable will be shared between files and applications

Comment: I tried --env CY_MODE=true this one but in headless mode for cypress I don't know if it is set. So I need to check if it was set when I run "npx cypress run". But I cannot see anything in console.log

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-4-env   It is setting cypress env variable but I need to set node env variable to check in NextJS

Comment: you can check your env variables in the test runner -> open test runner -> click on settings link = and you can check all variables that related cypress

Comment: Yes I can see. But I am not able to use this env variable in a javascript code for the NextJS. I can access this by Cypress.env('CY_MODE') in a cypress spec file but I need to access this env variable into the NextJS not in Cypress. Hope  it is clear for you.